# send json from php to autocomplete and add data attribute in input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

```js
[{
  "sysid": "39",
  "name": "John",
  "code": "060400000"
}]





$(document).on("input", ".autocomplete", function(event) {
  var name = $(this).prop('id').split('_').pop();
  $(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'autocomplete.php',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
          keypressed: request.term,
          name: name
        },
        success: function(data) {
          //response(data);
          response($.map(data, function(item) {
            return {
              name: item.name,
              code: item.code,
              sysid: item.sysid
            };
          }));
        }
      });
    },
    minLength: 2

  });
})
```

This is my sample data

```
[{
    "sysid": "39",
    "name": "John",
    "code": "060400000"
}]
```

In my autocomplete if I use `response(data);` in success and `$name[] = ucwords(strtolower($selected_row[$columnename]));` in php page all is good but I want to add additional information for my input text like code and sysid.. So I did

`$name[] = array('sysid' => $selected_row['sys_id'],'name' => ucwords(strtolower($selected_row[$columnename])),'code' => $selected_row[$columnecode]);` in php and in success

```
response($.map(data, function(item) {
    return {
        name: item.name,
        code: item.code,
        sysid: item.sysid
    };
}));
```

What I want to achieve is add `data-code` and `data-id`in input after completing autocmplete.

Is this possible?Any Ideas

`UPDATE`

Used this below but the one changing is the dropdown values what I want is the input to change like

```
<input data-id="39" data-code="060400000">

response($.map(data, function(item) {
    return {
        title: item.name,
        value: item.name
    };
}));
```

Comment: Q:Is this possible?A:yes,Q:Any Ideas? A: many

Comment: how to achieve the update @madalinivascu

Answer (score 0):

Use the render item function

```
$(".autocomplete").data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
 return '<li data-code="'+item.code+'" data-id="'+item.sysid+'">'+item.name+'</li>'
}
```

for more info [visit](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data)

Comment: im getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_renderItem' of undefined`